# SQL Server - substring from position to end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have to split a string, I need take the first 25 characters and then the others, this is my code

```
select  
    SUBSTRING(field, 1, 25),
    SUBSTRING(field, 26, (LEN(field)-25))
from table
```

but I'm getting this for the second substring:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function

What's wrong in that?

Comment: What if you don't have 25 characters? Then the `SUBSTRING(field, 25, xxxx)` doesn't really make sense - and if the `25` parameters is greater than the length of `field`, you get this error

Comment: LEN(column)-25 - why? Why not just substring (column, 26, 8000) or whatever the max of the column definition? Calculating the length is unnecessary. But still you need to make sure the string is at least 26 characters long and, if not, what to do in that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `stuff()`:

```
select left(field, 25),
       stuff(field, 1, 25, '')
```

The problem is that `substring()` doesn't accept a negative length, which your code calculates.